# Cam going on and off with hangouts

Tags: macbook-pro, webcam

have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015). 
When I connect to a meeting on hangouts, the cam keeps going on and off (the green light goes and off as well). 
I'm saying hangouts because that's the tool I use for doing such things. Do you know if there is a way to fix the problem?

(for now I'm not considering it to be an hardware problem)

**UPDATE**: this problem started after helpdesk changed my user domain. As a proof I switched to a local user and everything is working fine

Comment: Likely an upstream bandwidth issue.  I assume you mean Google Hangouts?

Comment: Does something local like Photo Booth have this problem as well?

Comment: @JMY1000 I've added an update

Comment: I'm having the same thing. Not in a domain.